# Actions in Github

Tags: github, github-actions

What's wrong, why I've getting an error?

Error: Process completed with exit code 123.

---

```
//# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

//# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
//# events but only for the main branch

on:

  pull_request:

    branches:
      - "**"
    paths:
     - '**.js'        
//# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel

jobs:

  build:

    //# The type of runner that the job will run on

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    //# Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job

    steps:

      //# Runs a single command using the runners shell

      - name: Check for Debugger string in js files
        run: |
          find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "Debugger" > answer.txt
          filesize=$(stat -c%s answer.txt)
          if (( filesize > 0 )); then
             exit 1
          else
             exit 0            
          fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably `xargs` returning 123, because grep returns with an exit code 1-125. GitHub Actions stops executing a script if any command returns a non-zero exit code.

xargs man page:

> xargs exits with the following status:
> [..]
> 123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125